# How to read "service --status-all" results

Tags: services

I need to identify the currently running services but I can't figure out the results of running `service --status-all`, I mean what does **?**, **-** and **+** mean ?

```
$ service --status-all
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ + ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ ? ]  atieventsd
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ ? ]  binfmt-support
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  brltty
 [ + ]  console-font
 [ + ]  console-setup
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ ? ]  dns-clean
 [ + ]  friendly-recovery
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ ? ]  irqbalance
 [ - ]  kerneloops
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  lightdm
 [ - ]  lm-sensors
 [ ? ]  mysql
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ ? ]  ondemand
 [ ? ]  pppd-dns
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  pulseaudio
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ + ]  resolvconf
 [ + ]  rfkill-restore
 [ + ]  rfkill-store
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ + ]  saned
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ + ]  setvtrgb
 [ ? ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ + ]  timidity
 [ + ]  udev
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  urandom
 [ + ]  virtualbox
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

And would running this command with sudo make any difference ? I tried it and in my case it didn't make any difference, but may it differ in other setups ?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

The output of `service --status-all` lists the state of services controlled by `System V`.

The `+` indicates the service is running, `-` indicates a stopped service. You can see this by running `service SERVICENAME status` for a `+` and `-` service.

Some services are managed by `Upstart`. You can check the status of all `Upstart` services with `sudo initctl list`. Any service managed by `Upstart` will also show in the list provided by `service --status-all` but will be marked with a `?`.

Reference: `man service`

Comment: May be of interest: output for services marked `-` & `+` will go to stdout, output for services marked `?` will go to stderr.

Comment: "Any service managed by Upstart will also show in the list provided by service --status-all but will be marked with a ?." This is not strictly true. Just tried both commands on a server. `service --status-all` gives me 43 services. `initctl list` gives me 93. Only a handful of those 93 are duplicates.

Comment: My Ubuntu machine does not list "Upstart services" as "?" by  **service --status-all**

Comment: @hfrmobile unless you are still on 14.04 or specify at boot time to use `Upstart` you are using 'systemd' now. I also no longer see "?" on my 16.04 system.

Comment: running 16.10 ...

Answer (score 32):

It's not documented in the manpage, but a quick look at the source confirms the first guess:

- `+`: the service is running
- `-`: the service is not running
- `?`: the service state cannot be determined (for some reason).

[The actual code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/sysvinit/trusty-updates/view/head:/debian/service/service#L68):

```sh
 if ! is_ignored_file "${SERVICE}" \
 && [ -x "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ]; then
         if ! grep -qs "\(^\|\W\)status)" "$SERVICE"; then
           #printf " %s %-60s %s\n" "[?]" "$SERVICE:" "unknown" 1>&2
           echo " [ ? ]  $SERVICE" 1>&2
           continue
         else
           out=$(env -i LANG="$LANG" PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "$SERVICEDIR/$SERVICE" status 2>&1)
           if [ "$?" = "0" -a -n "$out" ]; then
             #printf " %s %-60s %s\n" "[+]" "$SERVICE:" "running"
             echo " [ + ]  $SERVICE"
             continue
           else
             #printf " %s %-60s %s\n" "[-]" "$SERVICE:" "NOT running"
             echo " [ - ]  $SERVICE"
             continue
           fi
         fi
   #env -i LANG="$LANG" PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "$SERVICEDIR/$SERVICE" status
 fi
```

The conditions are:

- if the init script doesn't support a `status` command, the state is `?`.
- if the init script (with the `status` argument) exit status is zero *and* output is not empty, the state is `+`.
- otherwise the state is `-`.

Answer (score 2):

I find that running with/without `sudo` makes a difference.

Some services in `/var/run/` have read access only to root user. Those services show status `[-]` without `sudo`, and `[+]` with `sudo`.

Comment: Are you sure? some service statuses change dynamically; maybe you are just seeing variation

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `+` means the service is active/running, `-` means it is inactive/stopped, and `?` means that the command cannot conclusively determine whether it is active or not, as the service does not have a `status` command in the service script. The `service --status-all` command actually runs `service <service-name> status` for every available service.