# Is x11-common service still needed in 14.04 or later?

Tags: 14.04, xorg, services

I noticed that x11-common is reported as not-running with `sudo service --status-all`. And I recall Ubuntu working on a replacement for X, but am not aware of this being in use, yet.

When checking `ps -faux`, I see lightdm running, with a child-process `/usr/bin/X -core :0 ...`, so it seems X is still running.

Can I remove the x11-common service? Why would it be in the services, yet not be (reported as) started?

Note that this is a rather old machine, who has seen upgrades from very early Ubuntu-versions, it may very well be some cruft that remained around after re-configuring something in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x11-common` does not start a daemon. What it does do is make some directories, with correct permissions, etc. `service --status-all` reports it as not running, because for it to be considered as running, the exit status of `/etc/init.d/x11-commmon` should be zero, which it is, [and there should some output](https://askubuntu.com/a/646465/158442), which there isn't.

```
$ service x11-common status && echo yes
yes
```

Don't delete it.

Comment: Am I understanding you correct, when I summarize as "`service --status-all` is reporting the wrong status, because it is somewhat incompatible with the x11-common service"

Comment: @berkes yes, I suppose.