# systemctl, how to unmask

Tags: systemd

```
root@gcomputer:~# systemctl status x11-common
● x11-common.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I tried `systemctl unmask x11-common` and `systemctl unmask x11-common.service` but that did not change anything.

How do I unmask it?

Comment: In my case the file had been overwritten and was empty.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The commands you are using are [both correct](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units#unit-management). See also [the manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).

It seems the `unmask` command fails when there is no existing unit file in the system other than the symlink to `/dev/null`. If you `mask` a service, then that creates a new symlink to `/dev/null` in `/etc/systemd/system` where systemd looks for unit files to load at boot. In this case, there is no real unit file.

[Others seem to have similar issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729897/i-cant-unmask-a-service-on-kubuntu-wily-15-10)

`x11-common.service` was also masked on my system. You can fix it like this:

First check that the unit file is a symlink to `/dev/null`

```
file /lib/systemd/system/x11-common.service
```

it should return:

```
/lib/systemd/system/x11-common.service: symbolic link to /dev/null
```

in which case, delete it

```
sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/x11-common.service
```

Since you changed a unit file, you need to run this:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

now check the status:

```
systemctl status x11-common
```

if it doesn't say loaded and running (if the circle is still red), reinstall the package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall x11-common
```

and reload the daemon again

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

and check status once more

```
systemctl status x11-common
```

Now it's green and running :) The service has no systemd unit file, but systemd happily uses the script for it in `/etc/init.d` instead.

Comment: Ok, follow-up question: If it was even masked on your system, what is this service for? It seems as it is not really needed if it is masked for both of us.

Comment: @Albert [See here.]( http://askubuntu.com/questions/712276/is-x11-common-service-still-needed-in-14-04-or-later) seems the service works without the systemd unit file (it has a file in `/etc/init/`...). You might want to ask a new question. What I did made no apparent difference, only the service shows as loaded, enabled, stopped (it's active on startup) (green) instead of loaded masked dead (red). I should read my logs...

Comment: if an update for systemd comes by, the unit file is reinstalled, so this isn't really a structural solution

Comment: @hbogert does that happen even if there was no unit file apart from the symlink to `/dev/null`? You are right about my answer though. I would call this solution a workaround for a... confusing behaviour... of systemd

Comment: Could you describe your first sentence in terms of exact files which matter in this case (because I don't really understand the scenario your describing)?

Comment: @hbogert The service can't be unmasked in this case because it has no real unit file, just a symlink to `/dev/null` in the place where systemd looks for unit files with an appropriate name. I think that after "fixing" such a service using the hacky method described, it stays fixed (ie it loads) regardless of systemd updates, but I'm not entirely sure - maybe it makes a new bitbucket symlink, so I'm asking you if you know. Otherwise I'll check after the next systemd update myself. If I'm not making sense, I'm sorry, it's bedtime!

Comment: Non-conf files are always overwritten with update of a deb file. I just emulated an update of systemd, the symlink to /dev/null is recreated.

Answer (score 4):

Here I show how I remove the mask using systemctl

```
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit bluetooth.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)

$ sudo systemctl unmask bluetooth.service
Removed /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service.

$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; disabled; vendor preset: e>
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

$ sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service

$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; disabled; vendor preset: e>
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-07-30 08:50:04 +06; 2s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 23191 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9135)
     Memory: 1.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─23191 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps below:

1. `systemctl edit systemd-hostnamed`

   Add the 2 lines below then exit the editor (don't forget to save when prompted):

   ```
   [Service]
   PrivateNetwork=no
   ```
2. This will create an override.conf file with the above 2 lines in the directory:

   ```
   /etc/systemd/system/systemd-hostnamed.service.d/
   ```
3. The update systemd:

   ```
   systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
4. Then restart the service:

   ```
   systemctl restart systemd-hostnamed
   ```

You should now be able to run `hostnamectl` without it hanging.

Answer (score 2):

It could be your service has an empty override file, like this:

```
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; masked; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/redis-server.service.d
           └─limit.conf
```

Check if limit.conf is an empty file. If it is, please remove it. Then the service should be unmasked.

Comment: i have added my actions to orig question. Also after masking networkd. and reboot system intfc did not come up. So it is clear that networkd is managing the interface. How can I ensure that it is done by NetworkManager and not networkd ?