# proc-fs-nfsd.mount is masked : cannot unmask

Tags: systemd, nfs

The nfs server has been working without issue through a couple versions of Ubuntu now.

Today I was rebuilding one of my exported disks so stopped the nfs server, rebuilt the disk, then attempted to restart the nfs server. System complained:

```
proc-fs-nfsd.mount is masked
```

I found this question below which identifies the issue as a null service definition, and this is the explanation I found in other links. However in my case the service definition link is not to /dev/null so I don't know what's going on my case. (I don't see how the other answers to the linked question apply)

[systemctl, how to unmask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804946/systemctl-how-to-unmask)

Below you can see that the service link points to an actual file.

```
systemctl start nfs-kernel-server
  Failed to start nfs-kernel-server.service: Unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount is masked.
systemctl unmask proc-fs-nfsd.mount
systemctl start nfs-kernel-server
  Failed to start nfs-kernel-server.service: Unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount is masked.
file /lib/systemd/system/proc-fs-nfsd.mount
/lib/systemd/system/proc-fs-nfsd.mount: ASCII text
```

**Originally put as answer but failed after reboot**

> The most common fix I've seen is to remove the link to `/dev/null`,
>   but
>
> ```
>  file /lib/systemd/system/proc-fs-nfsd.mount
>  /lib/systemd/system/proc-fs-nfsd.mount: ASCII text
> ```
>
> However I deleted this file anyway and discovered that
>   `lib/systemd/system/proc-fs-nfsd.mount` *was* linked to `/dev/null`,
>   so I deleted that and reloaded the daemons.
>
> ```
>  sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/proc-fs-nfsd.mount
>  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
> ```
>
> And then restarted the nfs service
>
> ```
>  sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server.
> ```
>
> This succeeded.

Server worked well until it was restarted. It then failed:

```
systemctl start nfs-kernel-server
Failed to start nfs-kernel-server.service: Unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount not found
```

The currently working fix is

```
 sudo cp /etc/exports ~
 sudo apt purge nfs-kernel-server
 sudo apt install nfs-kernel-server
 sudo cp /etc/exports ~/exports.installed
 sudo cp ~/exports /etc
 sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel server
 systemctl status nfs-kernel-server
```

There is now a working NFS server.

```
 rm ~/exports ~/exports.installed
```

However I am not confident that all is well so I will not put this as an answer.

Comment: Did you try the top answer? From your post, it looks like you tried the same thing the other person tried in their question, not the answer. could you clarify?

Comment: @Jeff  Ah yes, thank you, I will clarify the question. In my case I followed the procedure to the point where I discover that the link is *not* to /dev/null but to an actual file. So I took that to mean that the answer did not apply to my case.

Comment: Your answer worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a systemd expert, but I think that worked for me :

```
rm /run/systemd/system/proc-fs-nfsd.mount
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Systemd is complaining that proc-fs-nfsd.mount is unmasked, which I assume is because there is a `/run/systemd/system/proc-fs-nfsd.mount` file which points to `/dev/null` and prevents systemd from mounting `/proc/fs/nfsd`.

I have no idea how that file ended up being created tough nor why NFS stopped working. I went through a lot of tries/error so I can't say for sure the two lines above are the ones that worked, but that's my understanding at this point.

Comment: Ok, this way it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem following a hard disk change, the content of my */etc/exports* becoming incorrect.

Even after fixing */etc/exports*, nfs did not start.

The problem is that there were a lot of links to */dev/null* in */run/systemd/system/*.

The solution was to do

```
sudo rm /run/systemd/system/*.mount
```

then to restart nfs.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Me neither.....

Comment: Happened again, tried again. No way...

Comment: But doing `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` afterwards and then `sudo service nfs-kernel-server start` actually works.