# Failed to start LSB: SANE network scanner server

Tags: networking, server, scanner, xsane

So my print-scanner Samsung SCX-4300 is working fine through USB, and instead, I connected it with "Networking USB Server" like the following link:

https://es.aliexpress.com/item/Wavlink-USB-2-0-red-LRP-servidor-de-impresi-n-USB-Hub-100-Mbps-compartir-una/32933067390.html

Through the server, the print is working fine but scanner doesn't work, and I followed the instruction of Ubuntu's tutorial:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaneDaemonTutorial?action=show&redirect=sane.d+tutorial

**1.** So I wrote on the terminal `sudo service saned restart`:

```
Failed to restart saned.service: unit saned.service is masked
```

**2.** Later, `sudo service saned status`:

```
● saned.service
   Active: inactive (dead)
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
```

Then, I research on the internet, and I found this web: [systemctl, how to unmask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804946/systemctl-how-to-unmask)

**3.** `file /lib/systemd/system/saned.service`:

```
/lib/systemd/system/saned.service: symbolic lik to /dev/null
```

**4.** I typed to check `sudo nano /run/systemd/generator.late/saned.service` and I found that there was completely empty.

**5.** `sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/saned.service` and then, later, `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

**7.** and finally, `systemctl status saned`:

```
● saned.service - LSB: SANE network scanner server
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/saned; generated)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-06-16 13:19:23 -05; 9min ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Process: 923 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/saned start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

jun 16 13:19:22 MS-7529 saned[923]:  * Starting SANE network scanner server saned
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 saned[944]: saned (AF-indep+IPv6) from sane-backends 1.0.27 starting up
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 saned[944]: do_bindings: [1] bind failed: Address already in use
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 saned[944]: do_bindings: [0] bind failed: Address already in use
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 saned[944]: do_bindings: couldn't bind an address. Exiting.
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 saned[944]: FATAL ERROR; bailing out, waiting for children...
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 saned[944]: bail_out: all children exited
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 systemd[1]: saned.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 systemd[1]: saned.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: SANE network scanner server.
```

**8:** So I went to check again `sudo nano /run/systemd/generator.late/saned.service`:

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/saned
Description=LSB: SANE network scanner server
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target
After=remote-fs.target
After=dbus.service
After=avahi-daemon.service

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
SuccessExitStatus=5 6
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/saned start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/saned stop
```

**9.** I typed again `sudo service saned status`:

```
● saned.service - LSB: SANE network scanner server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/saned; generated)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-06-16 13:19:23 -05; 1h 20min ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 923 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/saned start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

jun 16 13:19:22 MS-7529 saned[923]:  * Starting SANE network scanner server saned
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 saned[944]: saned (AF-indep+IPv6) from sane-backends 1.0.27 starting up
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 saned[944]: do_bindings: [1] bind failed: Address already in use
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 saned[944]: do_bindings: [0] bind failed: Address already in use
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 saned[944]: do_bindings: couldn't bind an address. Exiting.
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 saned[944]: FATAL ERROR; bailing out, waiting for children...
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 saned[944]: bail_out: all children exited
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 systemd[1]: saned.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 systemd[1]: saned.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jun 16 13:19:23 MS-7529 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: SANE network scanner server.
```

I couldn't find how to fix to connect scanner through the server.

So does anyone know how to fix this failure?