# Cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/apps: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory

Tags: command-line, snap

I am trying to install heroku cli using

```
sudo snap install heroku --classic
```

The command line says

```
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/apps: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

I tried `systemctl status snapd.service` this is the result :

```
snapd.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)  
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I tried  `systemctl restart snapd.service` it says:

```
Failed to restart snapd.service: Unit snapd.service is masked.
```

Any help on above problem in appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [systemctl, how to unmask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804946/systemctl-how-to-unmask)

Comment: For anyone seeing this issue with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) see - https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5126

Run this before attempting a snap install - it should work:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -yqq daemonize dbus-user-session fontconfig`


`sudo daemonize /usr/bin/unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target`


`exec sudo nsenter -t $(pidof systemd) -a su - $LOGNAME`

Comment: Add these lines to the /etc/wsl.conf (note you will need to run your editor with sudo 
`[boot]
systemd=true`
after that, you should run wsl.exe --shutdown

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Unmask the `snapd.service`:

```
sudo systemctl unmask snapd.service
```

Enable it:

```
sudo systemctl enable snapd.service
```

Start it:

```
sudo systemctl start snapd.service
```

Then try installing your desired app.

Comment: I am running WSL based on Ubuntu Linux, And running these instructions gives error after last command: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.

Comment: If you are using WSL then this answer is not applicable to your situation. Basically because there is no `systemd` on WSL in the first place. However [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5126) might be helpful to you.

Comment: I am inside a docker image of ubuntu. Running `systemctl start snapd.service` returns `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.`

Comment: @Jortega Did you ever find a solution? I'm thinking based on [other discussions](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/installing-and-running-snaps-without-systemd/3949/20) that trying to run snapd without systemd isn't worth the headache.

Comment: @Ravexina systemd is on WSL, but may be disabled. I had this issue with WSL on Ubuntu 24.04 pre-release, where systemd was disabled by default, and fixed it by adding ```[boot] systemd=true``` to `/etc/wsl.conf` and restarting WSL :)

Comment: @Andy I think my answer would solve your problem.

Comment: @Jortega I think my answer would solve your problem.

Comment: @BrianZ I think my answer would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

for a WSL-specific answer, I had this problem on WSL Ubuntu 24.04 pre-release where systemd was disabled, giving me errors like

```
$ snap install chromium
error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/chromium": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
$ sudo systemctl start snapd.service
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

and I fixed it by adding

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

to `/etc/wsl.conf` , then restarting WSL :) (starting PowerShell as administrator and running `wsl --shutdown`), now Snap works great.

In comments to Ravexina's answer, I think this would solve the problem of Andy, Jortega, and Brian Z..  but i have no way to ping them.

Comment: Followed all these steps on WSL 2 Ubuntu, no dice. Still having issues with Snap after restarting with `systemd` enabled via that config.

Comment: @ajmeese7 can you pastebin a log? ( for example http://paste.debian.net )