# Snap store isn't installing

Tags: snap, snap-store

I would like to install the Snap store, but I am getting this error:

```
root@localhost:~# sudo snap install snap-store
error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/snap-store": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

How do I resolve this error and install the Snap store?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/apps: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258137/cannot-communicate-with-server-post-http-localhost-v2-apps-dial-unix-run-sn)

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the `snapd` service is not running. Enable it with `sudo systemctl enable snapd.service`, and then start it with `sudo systemctl start snapd.service`, and then you should be able to install the snap store.

If enabling and starting it doesn't fix the error, run `sudo systemctl status snapd.service` to see what the status of the Snap daemon is, and if it mentions the word `masked`, try following [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1258139/1438484).