# Nextcloud maintenence mode bug snap install

Tags: server, snap, nextcloud

My snap nextcloud installation constandly changes maintenence mode in the `nextcloud/config/config.php`from false to true, everytime i cat the file, the mode changes after 5 seconds, i dont know what would make this happen. the command which list the snap processes also does not work.

i sometimes get on the nextcloud page but when i do the whole site does not have the css loaded and it looks very bugged.

Comment: ```sudo snap stop nextcloud
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/apps: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/apps: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258137/cannot-communicate-with-server-post-http-localhost-v2-apps-dial-unix-run-sn)

Answer (score -1):

i fixed the bug with these commands posted by this user:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1258139/1614418

my snap was 'dead' so it wasnt working properly.