# Snapd error: cannot install or remove any snap app Error: communicate with server: Post

Tags: 22.04, snap, snap-store

I can not install any app from snap or remove it from Ubuntu. Here I shared the error of snapshot. I read other relevant posts but none works for me.

I got the following error when I tried to remove it first for a fresh installation

sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd

[image]

[image]

I can not install any app from snap or remove it from Ubuntu. Here I shared the error of snapshot. I read other relevant post but none works to me.

Note: I followed following [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258137/cannot-communicate-with-server-post-http-localhost-v2-apps-dial-unix-run-sn) but it did not work

Comment: please alter the question and add the TEXT and not images. We can not copy the text of images and we can not search for the text in images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove snap from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035915/how-to-remove-snap-from-ubuntu)

Comment: Follow the second solution (manual) : https://askubuntu.com/a/1114686/1004020 . Do `umount` first if necessary