# How can I get this filesystem mount to work?

Tags: mount, nfs

I'm running Kybuntu 20.04.
I'm trying to mount a Synology NAS (Network Attached Storage) unit via a symlink. On bootup the unit doesn't get mounted, which is the problem. However, once my system gets going I can do the mount explictly or even with **mount -a**.

I've set up the symlink with

`ln -s /Music /mnt/synology`

I did that just once, on a previous login.  **/etc/fstab** contains the line

```
192.168.0.21:/volume1/NAS /mnt/synology nfs defaults 0 0`
```

Why doesn't the filesystem at 192.168.0.21 get mounted on every reboot?

The problem is trickier than I realized at first.  _netdev will ensure that the network is up and running, but will not ensure that the Synology unit is fully available.It can take several seconds at least from when the network comes online to when the Synology unit is fully accesssible.  I don't know how to test for that, since even when the Synology box is fully connected to the network there might be additional delays within the box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to setup ubuntu that fstab runs after network is connected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208568/how-to-setup-ubuntu-that-fstab-runs-after-network-is-connected)

Comment: I thought that putting _netdev in front of "defaults" would solve the problem, but for some reason t didn't.

Comment: As far as I understand, `defaults` is just a placeholder for when you don't want to declare any options yourself. But as soon as you name any option, you don't need to put `defaults` there too, any more. So I believe, in this case a single `_netdev` in the fourth column could suffice.

Comment: Please see [this related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312106/cifs-mount-problem-error-cifs-mount-failed-w-return-code-2) and check that related services are enabled and running. Please go through the comments under the question and answers as they contain some troubleshooting and information.