# How to unmask and start a dhcpd service?

Tags: server, services, dhcpd

[image]

I was about to start my `dhcpd` service but couldn't do it since it was masked.

I tried `systemctl unmask dhcpd.service` but it does not work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [systemctl, how to unmask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804946/systemctl-how-to-unmask)

Comment: thank you brother