# I think I got hacked 16.04 LTS

Tags: security, hacking

I'm running ubuntu on my laptop and while i was watching some videos, someone logged into my computer and started using it. I saw the mouse pointer starting to move and they started clicking things. I sort of panicked and unplugged the power cable straight away. I'm not sure if they got anything, is there a way to check if I've been compromised, and what should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: What applications do you have installed that somebody could login using? SSH server? Desktop-sharing software?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't your palm on the touchpad?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: not an expert, this is what i would do.

- start by disconnecting your laptop from the internet
- power up
- check all ports open with `nmap -PN 127.0.0.1` (and close them later if unneded)
- get which services/apps are using ports with `sudo netstat -tulpn`
- check which services are [running on start](https://askubuntu.com/a/422178/260379)

with that info i will start looking for anything suspicious.

You can take a look at rkhunter.

If it's only your account which is compromised (and not the root account), i will try to create a new one with sudo access and work the process from there.