# What is the difference between cat /etc/services and service --status-all?

Tags: services, process

I would like to know the difference between these commands to show linux services:

```
cat /etc/services
```

and

```
service --status-all
```

Comment: Pretty much everything. The two are almost entirely unrelated.

Comment: Look at /etc/services and you'll see some *really* archaic stuff that *never* been installed on Linux servers...

Answer (score 19):

The contents of `/etc/services` do not actually correspond to the services on your system. That file is actually a mapping of ports to the services that usually use them (say, port 22 by SSH). It's used by tools like `netstat` to give an understandable name in the output (instead of just dumping the port number). So it might, and usually does, have a large number of services listed that are not actually installed on your system.

The output of `service --status-all` is actually the status of installed services on your system.

See also:

- [How to read "service --status-all" results](https://askubuntu.com/q/407075/158442)
- [`man 5 services`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/service.5.html)
- [`man 8 service`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/service.8.html)

Comment: Would be perfect with references to man pages : http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/service.8.html and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/services.5.html