# Determine if a service is really running

Tags: services

According to

[How to read "service --status-all" results](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407075/how-to-read-service-status-all-results)

```
service --status-all
```

list the running services with `[+]`. On the other hand, you can check the status of a service with

```
service <name> status
```

Now both commands list the service `apache-htcacheclean` for me

differently.

```
✗ ✗ sudo service apache-htcacheclean status
● apache-htcacheclean.service - Disk Cache Cleaning Daemon for Apache HTTP Server
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache-htcacheclean.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: inactive (dead)

✗ ✗ sudo service --status-all
  [+] acpid
  [-] alsa-utils
  [-] anacron
  [+] apache-htcacheclean
  [-] apache2
  [+] apparmor
```

Why is that, what is correct now or have I overlooked anything?

Comment: Please don't do this Post the solution as an ANSWER.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Translated from: https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/laufender-service-ja-oder-nein/

> This is a very good example of why you shouldn't use the `service`
>   command since `systemd` (and thus `systemctl`) was introduced.
>
> You can look at the source code of the `service` command 
>   (`/usr/sbin/service`). With the `--status-all` option, this script changes to
>   `/etc/init.d` and executes each executable file located there with a
>   previously defined environment and the argument status. From this
>   call, the return value and the output are saved.
>
> A service receives the marker `[+]` if the return value of the executed
>   program is `0` and the length of the recorded output is not zero. Before
>   that, it is tested whether the output of the executed file contains
>   the string `usage:` (upper and lower case is ignored) in order to use
>   the marker `[?]` to put. For all other cases the result is `[-]`.
>
> Now an example:

```
/etc/init.d$ ls
acpid                console-setup.sh  grub-common        lvm2           mdadm-waitidle  plymouth-log    ssh
apache2              cron              hwclock.sh         lvm2-lvmetad   networking      procps          udev
apache-htcacheclean  cryptdisks        irqbalance         lvm2-lvmpolld  nfs-common      rpcbind         ufw
apparmor             cryptdisks-early  iscsid             lxcfs          open-iscsi      rsync           uuidd
apport               dbus              keyboard-setup.sh  lxd            open-vm-tools   rsyslog
atd                  ebtables          kmod               mdadm          plymouth        screen-cleanup

/etc/init.d$ ./apache-htcacheclean status
 * apache-htcacheclean is not running

/etc/init.d$ echo $?
0
```

> If you ask service directly about the status of a service, it will
>   instead be passed through a systemctl, which can then give a much more
>   correct answer.